# Why fiels is required in Symfony2 form

Tags: php, symfony

Can someone tell me why in form I have a filed that is required:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="client_invoice" name="client[invoice]" class="invoice-controller" value="1" required="required">
```

if in Entity I set:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
 *
 * @var boolean
 */
protected $invoice;
```

My gues is becouse in form builder I have:

```
$builder->add('invoice', 'checkbox', array('label' => 'form.client.invoice'));
```

and then 'required' value is automatically set to true (becouse of the 3rd parameter in add function). Am I right, or is there another reason that this field is required?

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#field-type-options-guessing

Comment: *"These field options are only guessed if you're using Symfony to guess the field type (i.e. **omit or pass null** as the second argument to add())."* You're passing `checkbox`. (but good call ;))

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Form fields are required by default in Symfony2. You can turn it off for a specified form field by:

```
$builder->add('invoice', 'checkbox', array(
    'label' => 'form.client.invoice',
    'required' => false,
));
```

Comment: I know I can set required to false. Fileds are automatically set to 'required' => false if you set nullable=true in entity.

Comment: Yes. It can be annoying if you use checkboxes but in other cases it is a good feature.

Comment: Fileds are not required if they are set to nullable in entity. I want to know why if I have them nullable in entity they are set to required when the form is generated.

Comment: Because you usually connects an entity to a form it inherits the properties of the entity fields. If you need some kind of data then you set it as nullable=false, because it is required for you. If some kind of data is optional, then it is nullable which means that it is not required. It seems logical to me.

Comment: Setting nullable = false in an entity is a Doctrine 2 mapping thing.  The forms know nothing about it.